FlexiLayout and Project Setup Station doesn't have the same results in ABBYY
I create a fl and is matched correctly, however in Setup station is not matching correctly.For example first image, in flexilayout 3 fields are correct matched. On second image I tested in Project Setup but don't recognize those 3 fields.
FLEXILAYOUT RESULT
PROJECT SETUP STATION RESULT
These are my pre-recognition properties:
PRE RECOGNITION PROPERTIES FL
These are my recognitio properties in ProjectSetup:
enter image description here
enter image description here
As you can see, I tried to configure with same properties on both sides. But it still works. Please help me. There's something wrong or I missed?
